# Azure, delete SQL Server Automatic StorageAccount before disabled the Automatic Backup. Can't disable it now

Tags: sql-server, azure, virtual-machine, backup, azure-storage

So as the title says we deleted by mistake the StorageAccount before disabling the Automatic Backup. SQL keeps trying to do the backup anyway (as per the Event Log) but there is no way to disable it. When disabling on the Portal it says:

Provisioning failed. StorageAccount 'hfidiag756' associated with VM 'hfidb' for boot diagnostics encountered an error. Please look at the error code for more information about the error.. StorageAccountNotFound

I tried recreating that account "hfidiag756" but then the error is StorageInternalError.
Also tried via PowerShell and no luck.

Want to avoid having to recreate the VM.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Recreating the storage account with the same name may partially help as you already did, try the bellow steps:

On the vault item dashboard, click All Settings to open the Settings blade.
Backup policy blade
On the Settings blade, click Backup policy to open that blade then check if you can edit the policy for the specific backup that's still running.

If you still get the error about storage, try stopping the protection set to the VM:

If you choose to stop protecting a virtual machine, you are asked if you want to retain the recovery points. There are two ways to stop protecting virtual machines:

The following [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-manage-vms#manage-backup-policies) contains a tutorial to try it:

> stop all future backup jobs and delete all recovery points, or
>   stop all future backup jobs but leave the recovery points
>   There is a cost associated with leaving the recovery points in storage. However, the benefit of leaving the recovery points is you can restore the virtual machine later, if desired. For information about the cost of leaving the recovery points, see the pricing details. If you choose to delete all recovery points, you cannot restore the virtual machine.